# Why do biotic combos seem to sometimes not explode?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So here I am, playing my little asari adept, and I'm slinging Warps and Throws at dudes, and I notice that sometimes when a dude has been Warped and then Thrown, he does not properly explode. Now, this does not please me; I want to see and hear that delightful blue boom-thunderclap that says "you did this right, and now several people are in serious worlds of pain as a result; this is why we bring biotics."

It just seems that sometimes a biotic explosion is not triggered when it should be, namely when I have Warped and Thrown someone. I mean, when it works, it is the best thing, but other times I feel like no matter how many times I alternate those two powers these guys will simply not let an explosion be triggered. Is it because someone might be shooting them? Is it because someone *isn't* shooting them? Is it because maybe someone else is Warping or Pulling or whatever? Is it because of wizards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're playing with a Tech Class, you might be setting off Tech Explosions instead. Overload + Throw or Energy Drain + Throw (in the case of Salarian allies) both result in Tech Explosions. In this case, the overload effect sits "on top of" the warp effect - that is to say, it is suppressed but not removed.

If you throw after warp-ing, the enemy remains blue, but you didn't hear an explosion, chances are you triggered a tech explosion instead. In this case, just keep throw-ing until you get the explosion.

If you're playing with other biotics, however, it is equally likely that one of them detonated your explosion when you weren't looking. If this is what has happened, you will need to reapply warp.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the monster, some will not be affected by warp. Might take 2 or 3 shots of warp for it to actually effect them. This is normally with the stronger enemies.

There is also a chance that someone else did a biotic explosion on your warp, happens a lot to me in some games. I don't recall fully, but believe with it being them triggering the explosion you may not see the effects of it do to internet lag.

If you see the enemy glowing blue and you hit them with throw and still no explosion, its the wizards.

Comment: This is wrong; All enemies are affected by Warp.

Comment: @RavenDreamer No downvote on a wrong answer?  For shame!! :)

Comment: @Stephen *part* of the answer was wrong. Part of it was also right.

Comment: Just going by what I have seen in games, I have also not played in over a week. But I do recall sometimes I would hit a monster with warp, they would not start to glow blue and no biotic combo.

Answer (score 0):

Biotic and Electrical combos can be triggered without being a killing blow on an enemy. In these cases, they'll take the effective damage from the combo, but they won't explode since they still have health left.